# will gulp have an issue compiling javascript 1.7 object destructing syntax?

Tags: gulp

I have seen this "destructing" syntax before but haven't ever used it. until now anyways. I want to pull in a [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) repo on github to handle my applications routing (making a single page app). but I noticed that it has this syntax

```
var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;
```

which is just a fancy way of writing

```
var Route = Router.Route
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler
var Link = Router.Link
```

so my question is does anyone know if gulp will have any issues compiling this from jsx to javascript?
Do I need to install any additional dependencies for this syntax?
I have done some research but couldn't find anything conclusive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default gulp, yes.  JSX syntax needs to be transpiled down to native js.  Take a look at [gulp-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-react) to see how you can deal with this.  Basically , it works in similar concept to other transpiled code (ie. coffeescript).  Convert to native before piping along to the next task.

Edit
after seeing you're edit, it looks like you also need to convert the ES6.  Take a look at the [react browserify](https://github.com/tcoopman/react-es6-browserify), it should help to get you going.  Basically the concept is the same, compile jsx/es6 to native js.  There's a section specific to the ES6 react components.

2nd Edit
Looks like gulp-react has an option to set to ES6.  I think if you add this line, it will work.

`.pipe(react({harmony: true}))`

```
//full example  
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('template.jsx')
        .pipe(react({harmony: true))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: I know about jsx and compiling it. Already using gulp-react... My question was about compiling that "newer" JavaScript syntax with gulp and if there are any resources I need for it or any documentation for support

Comment: I think I misunderstood originally.  `var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;`  To me that line in question just looks like ES6 destructuring (object matching).  You'll probably need to specify to use the ES6 in your gulp transpilation.  My edit gives a link with some examples in browserify which is what most people are using for the new syntax I believe.

Comment: i'm using browserify and reactify so my js task looks like this `.task('js', function() {
  return browserify(package.paths.app)
  .transform(reactify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source(package.dest.app))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(package.dest.lib));
})` do you know how you would add it in to that? and I'll be able to test tonight so if I haven't gotten back to you after then remind me with a comment :)

Comment: So one option (I think) is to put the browserify configs into a separate file and use vinyl to feed them into gulp.  Reactify comes with a flag you can use in browserify [see docs](https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify#es6-transformation).  I think you can have this config live somewhere separate, see this blog under [browserify + vinyl-transform](https://medium.com/@sogko/gulp-browserify-the-gulp-y-way-bb359b3f9623)

Comment: If you get stuck, put a gist of the gulpfile with the basic setup and I can take a look.